# PWA con Jquery Mobile, al minimizar en celular y luego volver activarla se bloquea

Tags: jquery, programación-móvil, pwa

Les comento que tengo una PWA hecha con jquery mobile y la "agregue al inicio" en el celular (iphone), el problema pasa cuando la tengo abierta y quiero ir a otra aplicación, al volver a la PWA se me bloquea y la tengo que cerrar y abrir de nuevo, con la consecuente perdida de tiempo porque tengo que ingresar de nuevo las credenciales de ingreso.

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: como puedo hacer para que no se muera la pwa al cambiar de pantalla en el celular?